# How to write RegEx for the Below Expression

Tags: regex

```
12345678912345678T / 14750,47932 SS
Vis à 6PC 45H Din 913 M  8x20
Art. client: 294519
QTE: 200 Pce
```

I want to write a RegEx which can find above stated multiline string type from a long txt file where Starting condition will be "18 digit long word" comprises with numbers and Uppercase alphabets and Ending condition shoould be "Pce"

I have written this much and it only reads first line but don't know what to write next

```
^[0-9A-Z]{18,18}.*
```

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`.` in most engines doesn't include new lines, hence your match stopping at the end of the line. You could either use the [DOTALL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll) flag if available, otherwise hack around with an "include-all" class, for example `[\s\S]` (a char that is either a space or not a space).

With a [lazy quantifier](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy), you could use for example:

```
^[0-9A-Z]{18}[\s\S]*?Pce$
```

Comment: This captures too much. If a 19 char string exists then this will capture it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a programming language so something like this would work:

```
/^[\dA-Z]{18}[^\dA-Za-z].*?Pce$/gms
```

- `^[\dA-Z]{18}` - start with 18 digits and/or capital letters
- `[^\dA-Za-z]` - not a digit nor letter
- `.*?` - anything, lazily

  - substitute with `[\s\S]*?` if single line modifier is not available to you
- `Pce$` - end with `Pce`
- `gms` - global, multi line, and single line modifiers

https://regex101.com/r/RXaAT4/1